# How to create an automation/loop for making qqplots using R?

Tags: ggplot2

**Is it possible to make an automation/loop for making qqplots of numeric columns in a data frame?**

**The following works for making a loop to create histograms using ggplot:**

*`x %>% keep(is.numeric) %>% gather() %>% ggplot(aes(value)) +facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free") + geom_histogram()`*

**But replacing the geom_histogram function with a qqplot function doesn't work for looping qqplots**

*`x %>% keep(is.numeric) %>% gather() %>% ggplot(aes(value))+ geom_qq(mapping = NULL)  +facet_wrap(~key, scales = "free")`*

**I have tried using various qqplot functions yet most of them return the following error:**

*`` Error: stat_qq requires the following missing aesthetics: sample
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred ``.

````
<error/rlang_error>
stat_qq requires the following missing aesthetics: sample
Backtrace:
  1. (function (x, ...) ...
  2. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  4. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5. ggplot2:::by_layer(function(l, d) l$compute_statistic(d, layout))
  6. ggplot2:::f(l = layers[[i]], d = data[[i]])
  7. l$compute_statistic(d, layout)
  8. ggplot2:::f(..., self = self)
  9. self$stat$compute_layer(data, params, layout)
 10. ggplot2:::f(..., self = self)
 11. ggplot2:::check_required_aesthetics(...)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.```*
````

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you need to change the call in the qqplot aesthetic to this:

`ggplot(aes(sample = value))`

The following code works for me:

```
x <- rnorm(100)

x %>% 
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  enframe(name = NULL) %>% 
  mutate(key = rep(c("cat1", "cat2"), 50)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = value)) +
  geom_histogram() +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free")

x %>% 
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  enframe(name = NULL) %>% 
  mutate(key = rep(c("cat1", "cat2"), 50)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(sample = value)) +
  geom_qq() +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales = "free")
```